# Why does ArcGIS Server return a PNG file by default unless I hit the refresh button?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

I'm trying to access a web service that returns a map image in different formats. It first always returns a .png file until I hit the refresh button. It then returns me the map in the correct format.

Do you know what could cause that?

`http://appserver/ArcGIS/services/City/MapServer/WMSServer?REQUEST=GetMap&Version=1.1.1&LAYERS=0,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13&SRS=4326&FORMAT=jpeg&BBOX=43.999861,32.999861,45.000139,34.000139&WIDTH=500&Height=500&Styles=`

Comment: Which refresh button are you hitting?  The one in ArcGIS Server Manager, or the one in your browser?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tried a similar query on ArcGIS online servers as well as my servers & it returns different formats, every time I change the 'FORMAT'. Can you clarify your question further?

Answer (score 1):

> http://appserver/ArcGIS/services/City/MapServer/WMSServer?REQUEST=GetMap&Version=1.1.1&LAYERS=0,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13&SRS=4326&FORMAT=jpeg&BBOX=43.999861,32.999861,45.000139,34.000139&WIDTH=500&Height=500&Styles=

Most probably the issue you have is that format you are requesting `FORMAT=jpeg&` doesn't exist, just check the GetCapabilities response with:

`http://appserver/ArcGIS/services/City/MapServer/WMSServer?REQUEST=GetCapabilitie&Version=1.1.1&service=WMS&`

I expect the jpeg image format will be reported as: `image/jpeg`; if the (any) parameter value is incorrect the server is at liberty to do whatever it likes...

One thing it may do is ignore the parameter, in which case you will get the default image format, often the default image format is the first listed in the GetCapabilities response.

Is `image/png` the first listed image format in your GetCapabilities response?